# paypal cancel url has spurious :80

Tags: paypal, coldfusion, cfml

When the post to the PayPal login page is complete there's a link at the bottom to cancel the transaction; this is, supposedly, set in the following hidden field:

```
"CANCELURL" value="https://secure.MySite.com/checkout/cancel.cfm"
```

However, what's happening with my integration is that it's going to the return URL I've set, but with a spurious `:80` in it:

```
"https://secure.MySite.com:80/checkout/SetExpressCheckout.cfm"
```

I don't understand where the `:80` is coming from as it's not specified anywhere.

Does anyone have any idea why I'm getting this?

Answer (score 2):

80 is the default port number used for HTTP requests.

All TCP and UDP requests use a specific 'port' - FTP default port is 21, default HTTPS is 443. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) is a list of TCP and UDP ports.

In a URL, adding `:80` after the domain name is simply specifying that the request is sent on port 80 - which, unless you changed it, will be the default port for HTTP requests. Using `http://mydomain.com:80` is the same as using `http://mydomain.com` as long as the web server is listening on port 80 as browsers will automatically send HTTP requests on port 80.

**EDIT:**

As noted below, the cancel URL is HTTPS, but the URL you posted with the `:80` is not. I also noticed that the URL you provided as the 'CANCELURL' is not the same one you posted with the `"80` added to it. Maybe you need to provide more details.

There might be something in the API that you need to set to tell it to use HTTPS (port 443) over HTTP (port 80).

Comment: What do you make of his HTTPS request being on :80 instead of :443?

Comment: I would hazard a guess that something in the API is not catching the HTTPS in the cancel URL - will update answer to reflect possible solution.

Comment: I've had a look through the API files to see if there's any way of telling the the application to use HTTPS or HTTP but haven't found anything.

Comment: The URLs I gave were examples of the problem not actual samples, although the do both start with https - here's the real filepath (but without the domain)

"https://secure.MyDomain.com/checkout/paypal/cancel.cfm"

It's a weird issue that I've never seen before and only seems to have appeared recently. I changed the method of database definition in my application recently but I can't see how this could have affected the post to PayPal - confused...